# Invoking Swift Protocol Initializers

Tags: ios, swift, types, static, swift-protocols

Swift 5, on XCode 11.2.1.  I've programmed in Java forever, and am only moderately skilled in Swift at this point, so some of my understanding is colored by Java idioms.

Suppose we provide a protocol, or possibly a pseudo-abstract class, which can be implemented in a separate module.  Then the programmer passes a reference to their class back to code in the first module, which instantiates their class.  Now, in Java this was difficult because you couldn't make any guarantees what initializers/static methods a subclass would define.  However, in Swift, you can.  This is neat.  EXCEPT, I haven't yet found a way to use them.  What I'd *expect* would be that you could have code like e.g.

```
protocol FooP {
  init(s: String)
}

func instantiate(clazz: FooP.Type) -> FooP {
  return clazz.init(s: "qwerty")
}
```

...OOOOORRRR that actually DOES work, exactly as I'd hoped.  I think in my tests I just failed to find the right combination of CLASS/.Type/.self to clue me in to the possibility of success.

Since I haven't found any other information about this possibility, despite searching for 30-60 min, I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you CAN use the static methods given by a protocol, even when the classes involved (not instantiations thereof) are cast to their protocol.  You can even use generics to make the example `instantiate` method more conveniently have return type of the type you give it, though that causes a different problem as shown below.  Here's a bunch of code demonstrating things you can and can't do:

```
public protocol ProtocolTest {
    init(s: String)

    static func factory(s: String) -> Self
}

public class Foo : ProtocolTest, CustomStringConvertible {
    public let s: String

    public required init(s: String) {
        self.s = s
    }

    public class func factory(s: String) -> Self {
        return Self(s: s)
    }

    public var description: String { return "{\(Self.self)|s:\"\(s)\"}" }
}

public class Bar : Foo {
}

public func instantiateGeneric<T : ProtocolTest>(clazz: T.Type) -> T {
    return clazz.init(s: "qwertyGeneric")
}

public func instantiateNongeneric(clazz: ProtocolTest.Type) -> ProtocolTest {
    return clazz.init(s: "qwertyNongeneric")
}

public func run() {
    let ptts: [ProtocolTest.Type] = [Foo.self, Bar.self]

    // Success
    let aInit : Bar = Bar.init(s: "qwertyInit")
    // Success
    let aGeneric : Bar = instantiateGeneric(clazz: Bar.self)
    // Compile error: Cannot convert value of type 'ProtocolTest' to specified type 'Bar'
    let aNongeneric : Bar = instantiateNongeneric(clazz: Bar.self)

    for ptt in ptts {
        // Success
        let bInit : ProtocolTest = ptt.init(s: "qwertyInit")
        // Compile error: Protocol type 'ProtocolTest' cannot conform to 'ProtocolTest' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
        let bGeneric1 : ProtocolTest = instantiateGeneric(clazz: ptt)
        // Compile error: Cannot invoke 'instantiateGeneric' with an argument list of type '(clazz: ProtocolTest.Type)'
        let bGeneric2 = instantiateGeneric(clazz: ptt)
        // Success
        let bNongeneric : ProtocolTest = instantiateNongeneric(clazz: ptt)
        // This works too, btw:
        let bFactory : ProtocolTest = ptt.factory(s: "qwertyFactory")
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what's up with `instantiateGeneric` in the loop.  It seems like a reasonable line of code.  Let me know if you have an explanation.  Perhaps regarding the `<T : ProtocolTest>`, `ProtocolTest` doesn't technically conform to `ProtocolTest`, or perhaps it must be a strict subclass?  Not sure.  It would be nice to be able to use the same method for both uses, but I'm pretty pleased with what I can do, already.  This discovery may be enough to get me to actually LIKE Swift, haha.

Comment: Fun fact: in a class, `static func` is equivalent to `final class func`.

Comment: Additional fun fact: it seems that the moment you try to get fancy with your types beyond what I showed above, Swift immediately cracks down on you.  For instance, apparently you CANNOT use a generic class without specifying the type parameters.  And there aren't any wildcards.